# How to pipe from child process split at 4096 bytes?

Tags: c++, node.js

I am calling a c++ program from a nodejs script using child_process.spawn.  The c++ program uses std::cout to pipe data back to the nodejs script.  Typically this program pipes back JSON that is longer than 4096 bytes.  My node script (or c++ program?) will split this JSON into multiple 4096 byte chunks so that child.stdout.on('data') is called several times for a single response.

Is there a way to increase this chunk size or have the child process tell me that more data is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around this kind of problem is to just use some sort of delimiter. In the case of JSON, many people just use newline-delimited JSON. So append `\n` after your JSON string in your C++ program and then just keep buffering in your node program until you see a `\n`. Split there, and start buffering the next message.

Comment: The problem with this method is that I have a progress bar being emited as well.  Essentially I have a for loop which appends a value to a JSON array and also outputs a progress report.  I could store the value in a c++ vector and then loop over it at the end but that is inefficient from a cpu and ram standpoint.

Comment: In that case, just use a different file descriptor for the progress data or emit the JSON on a different file descriptor. You could use stderr or a completely new fd. node lets you specify your own custom stdio fds and then from the C++ side you can just start writing to that fd. curl does something like this where they show progress data on stderr and actual data comes in on stdout.